# AngularJS - two ng-repeats where first.id =second.id

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to show name of city against the city id I receive from branches. What is the angular way of doing it?

```js
$http.get(baseURL + '/city/getList?token=' + token)
  .then(function(response) {
    $scope.cities = response.data.data;
  });

$http.get(baseURL + '/store/getAllBranch?token=' + token)
  .then(function(response) {
    $scope.branches= response.data.data;
  });
```

```html
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in branches| orderBy:'name'">
    <td>{{x.name}}</td>
    <td>{{x.address}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="city in cities track by x.city">{{city.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: show your objects structure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a filter to convert cityID to cityName

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in branches| orderBy:'name'">
    <td>{{x.name}}</td>
    <td>{{x.address}}</td>
    <td>{{x.cityId | cityName}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
app.filter('cityName', function(cityId) {
    return function(cityId){

    for(var ci = 0; ci < cities.length; ci++)
    {
      if( cities[ci].id == cityId )
        return cities[ci].name;
    }

    return '';
  };
});
```

And use it like that..

But this way is not good for performance. If you could declare related city names in related branches then you can just print that to screen with no calculation.

Comment: Can you please help me implement this filter correctly, I get this error
Unknown provider: cityProvider <- city <- cityNameFilter

I am updating the code and adding the filter above.
I am new to angularJS, I would really appreciate your help, thanks

Comment: @Tidya You'll need to add the JS file you're writing the filter in to your main index.html file. Otherwise Angular won't be able to find the filter. And here 'app' is the name of your module. Another way is to use a getter: `angular.module('...').filter('...')`

Comment: Check the filter name. Are you using it like you declare it. If it is same then check the app you declared the filter is same app that you using the filter on html

Comment: I am using your exact code under my controller, the name of my module is "app". I only change x.cityId to x.city

Answer (score 0):

The 'angular way' is to construct an object which will be data-wise identical to how your table should look like and then you'd use `ng-repeat` to display the info.

You say you have the city id given in your branch. So you can just construct an object in which you push all your city names:

```
$scope.tableInfo = [];
for(var i = 0; i < branches.length; i++) {
    var tableCell = {
        name: branches[i].name,
        address: branches[i].address,
        city: branches.filter(function(element){
            for(var city in cities) {
                if(element.cityId === city.id) return city.name;
            }
        })[0];
    };
}
```

That [0] is there because it'll always be a 1-element array(because of the filter function).

In the HTML, just use a `<table>` to show the `tableInfo` object.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="tableCell in tableInfo">
        <td>{{tableCell.name}}</td>
        <td>{{tableCell.address}}</td>
        <td>{{tableCell.city}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This way is actually very similar to the other answer above, just that there an angular filter is used instead of using the native filter function in JS arrays.

Comment: Actually my json object contains so many other fields too so i feel like it is a bit of an over-head. Dont you think so?